# Закрыть AlertDialog со своим View

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Открываю диалог в фрагменте используя свой Viewю

```
var dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setView(filtresView)
            .setCancelable(true)
        dialog.show()
```

Нахожу кнопку в диалоге для закрытия

```
saveFiltres = filtresView.findViewById(R.id.saveFiltres)
```

Как можно по нажатию на эту кнопку закрыть AlertDialog ?
Стандартные методы по типу dismiss и cancel не работают

Comment: Должны работать. Как именно они у вас не работают?

Comment: У объекта dialog нет таких методов просто

Comment: Возможно это у AlertDialog.Builder класса таких методов нет. Попробуйте на вашем билдере `build()` метод вызвать